# select first visible row after filter ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I can't force to select first row after applied filter. So when I'm loading my page to select first row I use:

```
      gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[0]);
```

this is from API documentation and it is clear.
Now, I'm trying to select first row after filter. 
I have singleFilter function which comes from official documentation

```
 $scope.singleFilter = function( renderableRows ){
           var matcher = new RegExp($scope.filterValue);
           renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
               var match = false;
               [
              'name', 'company', 'email'
               ].forEach(function( field ){
                   if (field.indexOf('.') !== '-1' ) {
                       field = field.split('.');
                   }
                   if ( row.entity.hasOwnProperty(field) && row.entity[field].match(matcher) || field.length === 2 && row.entity[field[0]][field[1]].match(matcher)){
                       match = true;
                   }

               });
               if ( !match ){
                   row.visible = false;
               }
           });
           var rows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows();

           var first =  function(array, n) {  
                  if (array == null){   
                  return void 0;
                  }
                  if (n == null) {  
                  return array[0]; 
                  }
                  if (n < 0) {
                  return [];
                  }
                  return array.slice(0, n); 
           }; 

           console.log(first(rows))
           $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(first(rows));

           return renderableRows;
       };
```

where I get the length of visible rows

```
           var rows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows();
```

thru simple script I get first row

```
       var first =  function(array, n) {  
              if (array == null){   
              return void 0;
              }
              if (n == null) {  
              return array[0]; 
              }
              if (n < 0) {
              return [];
              }
              return array.slice(0, n); 
       }; 
       console.log(first(rows))
```

then I'm trying to apply selection

```
 $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(first(rows));
```

But unfortunately no success. Where is my mistake? I appreciate any help.
[**My plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ym8EM4lz2WgjzTHFmJCy?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a working plunker below.

The reason this is not working is because the visible rows that you are getting is all of the rows, and not just the filtered rows. The reason that is all of the rows is because you are calling for them before returning the filter. I've created logic using what we are knowledgeable about at this point, which is what *will* be returned once the function completes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LIcpOs7dXda5Qa6DTxFU

```
 var filtered = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < renderableRows.length; i++) {
   if (renderableRows[i].visible) {
     filtered.push(renderableRows[i].entity)
   }
 }

 if (filtered.length) {
   $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(filtered[0]);
 }
```

Comment: whoa!, works like magic, thank you for your description, I appreciate it!